# Add more than just req.user when deserializing in passport in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

[Passport restores the user object retrieved from database to `req.user` in its `.deserializeUser` method.](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/)

I was wondering if I could get some other things like `req.cart` or `req.inventory` that are all related to the user but stored in a different database, all through the same `.deserializeUser` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom middleware for this.  Demo code:

```
// ...
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // the use logged in.
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    // Fetch the user information from other databases by `req.user.id`.
    // Store the returned information as `req.cart` and `req.inventory` separately.
  };

  next();
});
```